# RN App Crashes on release in Google Play Store with: com.facebook.react.common.c: TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, react-native-hermes

Every time I deploy my app to Google Play, the automated Google testing devices crash, throwing a Fatal Exception mentioned in the title. I am unable to replicate the issue on my Emulator.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Stack Trace:**

```
Process: XXXXXX, PID: 6643
com.facebook.react.common.c: TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null, js engine: hermes, stack:
value@1:1574391
anonymous@1:1565462
oe@1:2225838
onPress@1:2226713
value@1:262899
value@1:262506
onResponderRelease@1:261783
o@1:99044
h@1:99101
g@1:99133
b@1:99265
xe@1:102719
H@1:100823
anonymous@1:103079
ke@1:158244
_e@1:102627
Re@1:102916
receiveTouches@1:152479
value@1:78850
anonymous@1:77331
value@1:78295
value@1:77289
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(Unknown Source:134)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:147)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:21)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

**react-native -v**

```
react-native: 0.64.3
```

**react-native info**

````
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.22000
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    Memory: 7.04 GB / 15.74 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.5 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
    npm: 8.5.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version     2020.3.0.0 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7621141
    Visual Studio: Not Found
  Languages:
    Java: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found```
````

Comment: Aren't you calling a show function in your js code like toast.show() ?

Comment: @Mohammad I am, but I haven't ran into any issues with it. I can't replicate any crash, so I assumed it would be something else. I can try looking into that.

Comment: could you please share more info with me. cause i'm getting this error some times in production too

Comment: @Mohammad what more info are you looking for?

Comment: what is the show function? is it for any specific package you are using?

Comment: It did end up being a difficult-to-replicate issue with Toast.show().  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: And are you using https://github.com/arnnis/react-native-toast-notifications#readme ? Did you fixed the issue?